# How to refactor this constructor so it is testable?

Tags: php, unit-testing, tdd, phpunit

I have a class that is a container for a bunch of module objects.  Right now the container takes in an array of file paths, then includes the files and instantiates the modules

```
class module {
    function execute();
}

class container {
    public $Name;
    public $Modules;

    public __construct($Obj){
      $this->Name = $Obj->Name;
      foreach($this->Modules as $M){
          include_once($M);
          $className = $this->GetClassName($M);
          $this->Modules[] = new $className;
      }
    }

    public execute(){
      foreach($this->Modules as $M){
          $M->execute();
      }
    }
}
```

I'm not certain what the best way to refactor this so that it is easily testable is.

```
class containerFactory{
    public function createContainer($Obj){
        $C = new Container($Obj);
        $C->InstiateModules();
        return $C;
    }
}
class container{
    public function InstiateModules(){
        $tmp = array();
        foreach($this->Modules as $M){
            include_once($M);
            $className = $this->GetClassName($M);
            `enter code here`$this->Modules[] = new $className;
        }
        $this->Modules = $tmp;
    }
    public function __construct($Obj){
        $this->Name = $Obj->Name;
        $this->Modules = $Obj->Modules;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions as to what else I should do?
Thanks

Comment: I am fail to see what is not tesable even in first version...
bwt, your constructor uses not initialized $this->Modules, how so?

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you could do:

1. Keep the code as it is, and test that object actually does what its supposed to do. You'd do that by passing a known array to the constructor, and then testing that those files were actually included and those modules actually imported. I'm not familiar with PHP, but I'm assuming there is a method to check if a file has been imported / module initialized.
2. If the above methods aren't available, then you can cut down your uncertainty footprint... you'd do this by having the import actions and initialization actions in a separate class, and testing that this class is correctly calling the importer and initializer for each of the files after parsing them. Mocking / stubbing the importer and initializer will be necessary.